# To check access for 1hr

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I want to know how to grant access for 1hr to the guest users. I have tried it's not working

```
Guest.findOne({ email: email})
        .then(user => {
            if(user){
                //Users exist
                if( Guest.createdAt + (0*1*60*60) < Date.now){

                res.render('Guestlogin');}
                // res.render('Guestboard');
                else{
                    res.render('Guestboard');
                }
        }else {
        const newUser = new Guest({
        email,
        name
         });
         newUser.save();
         return res.redirect('/Guestboard');
        }
```

Comment: hello Ashutosh. Please type a few lines on what exactly you want to achieve in more detail and the flow of your application when asking a question. The code can be formatted better and I am making that change.

There are many ways to implement gues logins but I can't help unless you give some more information. Do you use `jwt` or `sessions`. At what stage are you creating a gues object and more importantly what is the current error you are getting.


Also I belive it should be `(1000*60*60)` to represent 1hr in milliseconds.

Comment: Actually, I'm using *sessions* not *jwt*.  Actually I have created a login page with email and name after which I want the guest user to access the page for 1hr for that, I have created the condition  **if( Guest.createdAt + (1*60*60) < Date.now)**.   There is no error  and page is redirected to **guestdashboard**

Comment: Understood, but your multiplication will always return 0 since you are multiplying with it. The code should work. Just try this change. Also can you log the value of `Guest.createdAt + (0*1*60*60)` to ensure it is giving valid results.

Comment: I have tried this also not working. this **Guest** is a Mongoose Schema with having this field **createadAt **which stores current date, through this im trying validate user for 1hr only.

Answer (score 0):

OK so the `user` in the first then has your actual data. The `createdAt` is an ISO String hence we add the `+` to convert it into milliseconds and then add 1hr to it. If it is greater than `Date.now()` then more than 1hr has passed.

The last save function has been modified. You should ideally wait for the results of the save function to confirm your guest has actually been saved before return res object.

While the code is fine, you should check out `async/ await` as a superior alternative to using `Promises`.

```
Guest.findOne({
    email: email
  })
  .then(user => {
    if (user) {
      //Users existh
      if (+user.createdAt + (1000 * 60 * 60) < Date.now()) {
        // It has been over 1hr
        res.render('Guestlogin');
      } else {
        res.render('Guestboard');
      }
    } else {
      const newUser = new Guest({
        email,
        name
      });
      return newUser.save();
    }
  })
  .then(result =>  {
     return res.redirect('/Guestboard');
  }
```